# Compiling font awesome 4.5.0 with ruby sass

Tags: ruby, fonts, sass, font-awesome

I'm trying to compile Font Awesome (v4.5.0) from the sass source using the sass gem `v3.4.19 (Selective Steve)`. I'm compiling with

```
sass sass/font-awesome.scss css/font-awesome.css
```

using the defaults set by font awesome, i.e. fonts are in '../fonts', however upon compiling all the source, all fa classes display the following square rather than the unicode value:

```
.fa-lemon-o:before {
  content: ""; 
}
```

I thought this was an encoding issue, but all the files appear to be using the `utf-8 encoding`. I suspect it's the sass gem ignoring the encoding, but i've tried forcing it with `-E utf-8`

I'm can't seem to see what I'm doing wrong/what I've missed. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there's a breaking change in `3.4.x` versions of sass that cause the above issues. However there's a reusable function that can be used to force a unicode value out.

More information here: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1395#issuecomment-57658736